Understanding what Arvo meant about "Total Phase Space Density"
In James Richard Arvo's 1995 PhD thesis
"Analytic Methods for Simulated Light Transport"
at Stanford University, he introduces on page 26 "total phase space density" and states that it is not invariant along lines, unlike "phase space density", which he has just proved is invariant along lines.
Here, "phase space" is $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathcal{S}^2$ with the measure $\rho$, being the product of the Lebesgue measures on those two factors. Points in phase space represent possible positions and directions of travel of photons. The phase space density is a $\rho$-integrable function $n(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{u})$ on phase space such that the "photon content", which I understand to mean "photon count" (the discrete number of photons is approximated by a real number, which is reasonable since the photons are very small and very numerous) in a region $S$ of phase space is given by integrating $n$ over $S$ with respect to $\rho$. In other words, $n$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of photon content with respect to the "geometric" measure $\rho$ on phase space.
Using the notion of the time-evolution operator $E_t$ which acts on subsets of phase space by allowing the photons to move at speed $v$ for time $t$:
$$
E_t(S) \equiv \{(\mathbf{r}+tv\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{u}) : (\mathbf{r},\mathbf{u}) \in S\}
$$
Arvo proves that, in steady-state, in empty space, the phase-space density $n(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{u})$ is constant along the straight line through $\mathbf{r}$ in the direction $\mathbf{u}$.
He then points out that not all radiometric quantities share this invariance property, giving as an example the total phase space density, being the integral of phase space density over all directions $\mathbf{u}$ in the unit sphere:
$$
\hat{n}(\mathbf{r}) \equiv \int_{\mathcal{S}^2} n(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{u}) d\sigma(\mathbf{u})
$$
He explains that, given a bounded, measurable set $S$ in phase space, $\hat{n}(\mathbf{r})$ must decrease everywhere in the set $E_t(S)$ when $t$ is sufficiently large. He states that this follows from the fact that $\hat{n}(\mathbf{r})$ is bounded above by the product of the solid angle subtended by $S$ at $\mathbf{r}$ and the maximum phase space density attained within $S$, and refers the reader to the following diagram:

I have been trying to sketch a proof of the claim that total phase space density must eventually decrease, everywhere in $E_t(S)$, but without success. Here is what I have tried:
Let $\pi_1(S) = \{\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^3 : \exists \mathbf{u}\in\mathcal{S}^2, (\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{u})\in S\}$ and let $S_{\mathbf{r}} = \{\mathbf{u}\in \mathcal{S}^2 : (\mathbf{r},\mathbf{u})\in S\}$. Writing $\hat{n}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{u}) \equiv \hat{n}(\mathbf{r})$ (there is no actual dependence on $\mathbf{u}$), I think we have that
$$
\int_{S}\hat{n}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{u}) d \rho =
\int_{\pi_1(S)} \int_{S_{\mathbf{r}}} \hat{n}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{u}) d \sigma(\mathbf{u}) d \lambda(\mathbf{r}) =
\int_{\pi_1(S)} \hat{n}(\mathbf{r}) \int_{S_{\mathbf{r}}} d \sigma(\mathbf{u}) d \lambda(\mathbf{r}) =
\int_{\pi_1(S)} \hat{n}(\mathbf{r}) \sigma(S_{\mathbf{r}}) d \lambda(\mathbf{r})
$$
and that
$$
\int_{E_t(S)} \hat{n}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{u}) d \rho =
\int_S \hat{n}(\mathbf{r} + tv\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{u}) d \rho =
\int_{\pi_1(S)} \int_{S_r} \hat{n}(\mathbf{r}+tv\mathbf{u}) d\sigma(\mathbf{u}) d \lambda(\mathbf{r})
$$
but here I am stuck.
My question is: How to prove Arvo's claim about the total phase space density ?
